# Does using the latest Android operating system in development really matter?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android project and now I am facing many problems.

I wanted to know if newer problems are more stable or if all versions of Android would cause the problems that I am having?

Comment: Basically android operating system is not important. Important thing is what Android API you want to support. Generally people keep API 19 as minTargeted.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it does because in the world of mobile whenever a new update drops, a large audience tends to download the update and use the new version.

It's always a good idea if you can beta test your apps on the new version making sure that your application does not get negative feedback for the new update even though with the new OS you might not have to write a single line of code but it's recommended that you run your tests with the new OS just to be sure.

What I do as a practice is to support the last 3 versions of the mobile OS unless the business tells us that they want to support way older versions.

In the question you mentioned you are facing problems, can you please elaborate those or maybe you can read the document more or other StackOverflow forms to know how you can improvise.

Comment: please explain in the comments as why this was marked as -1